# In Sage Math, how do you implement a symbolic product? specifically I want the qPochhammer

Tags: sagemath

Note : on math.stackexchange I searched for the following keyword combinations:
sage math prod 
sage math prod product
and found nothing so I think this is a new question.

I want to implement a symbolic product, namely the qPochhammer symbol.

I tried

prod( 1 - x*q**i for i in (0 .. (n-1) ) )

but it says TypeError: 
unable to simplify to float approximation

If n is an integer greater than 1, 
prod( 1 - x*q^i for i in (0..2) )
it does what's expected
-(q^2*x - 1)*(q*x - 1)*(x - 1)

But I'd like a symbolic version or at least the best way to make it a function.  Thanks! - #ernestyalumni @ernestyalumni

Comment: Please use LaTeX (put mathematical expressions between $ ... $) to make your post easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this might be a solution for you. (Implement as a function:
[[Sage Cell Server]](http://aleph.sagemath.org/?q=tmxplq))

```
x = var("x")
q = polygen(ZZ, "q")
qPochhammer = lambda n: prod([ 1 - x*q^i for i in range(n + 1) ])
print qPochhammer(2) # for example
```

Comment: Thanks @Orat!  This is helpful.